# Sharpcompress write in Program Files folder

Tags: vb.net, sharpcompress

I'm trying to write some files in my folder which's inside `Program Files folder`... I'm getting error `"Access denied"` every time I try to write them... I tried to open the .exe (which makes the extraction) in `Administrator mode` and change folder rights to "Everyone"/"All Rights" and I still got problem with permissions.

**Code:**

```
    Using archive As IArchive = ArchiveFactory.Open(PastaDownload & "\" & NomeRAR)
        For Each entry In archive.Entries
            If Not entry.IsDirectory Then
                entry.WriteToFile(PastaSistema, New ExtractionOptions With {.ExtractFullPath = True, .Overwrite = True})
            End If
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: The most appropriate solution is to not do that. Windows provides various dedicated folders for various types of files to which you can write. You should use one of those.

Comment: ... and those folders are listed in [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

Comment: Got it... Is there any other solution? I need a web updater... That's the only easy solution that I found

Comment: For an installer, you probably will be much better served using one of the many deployment tools that already exist rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.  Maybe ClickOnce or Squirrel or the like, or a msi file

Comment: I'm using a msi as installer, but didn't like it... I'll give a try in "ClickOnce" and "Squirrel"